# begin end or brackets for bash?

Tags: bash, syntax

I was trying to do some bash programming and wanted to make it somewhat structural.
My questions is if I want to make a block code embedded in a bracket like the Pascal begin & end or the C {}, just to put a logically atomic group of commands together, is there a way in BASH to do it.

I can think of using a vacuous conditional or loop, but it's kind of ugly.

Thanks

Comment: In most languages you only use begin/end brackets around the bodies of loops, if, functions, switches, etc. Bash has `do/end`, `if/fi`, `case/esac` for this. What else do you need structure for?

Comment: @Barmar `do/done`, actually. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash supports braces.

```
{
  cmd1
  cmd2
}
```

Note that there *must* be a command separator before the closing brace.

```
{ cmd1 ; cmd2 ; }
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Should have guessed that the C way works. The other answer referring to gnu compound commands is also helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't really have variable scoping, so besides flow control, I don't think you will achieve much. Why not use some functions?

Comment: Scoping can be achieved with a subshell, and command grouping can be used to pipe many bits of output into a single command invocation. `{ foo ; bar ; } | baz`

Comment: Agree. But while spawning subshells to avoid collision between a mess of unintended globals might help you structure your code, you will often gain an unpleasant resource consumption. Bottom line, it doesn't really scale.

Comment: @mogul: Braces don't create subshells, just logical groupings. You may be thinking of parentheses, which do create subshells.

Comment: but this still prints 222, meaning the 123 initially loaded to X, outside the scope got overwritten: `X=123; { X=222; }; echo $X`

Answer (score 0):

Note that bash blocks aren't "atomic" in any particular sense.  See the bash manual page (i.e. run `man bash` if on a unix system), or look it up online:

```
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html
```

You should start in section 3.2.4, Compound Commands.